# Proof claimed that almost all zeroes of the Riemann zeta function lie on the critical line

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

There have been many results in recent years on the natural density of zeta zeroes on the critical line, with the best bound commonly accepted (as far as I'm aware) that

$$\liminf_{t\to\infty} \frac{N_0(t)}{N(t)} > 0.4128\dots$$

by [Feng](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X11002319) (here $N_0(t)$ is the number of zeroes $\chi$ on the critical line with $|\Im(\chi)|<t$ and $N(t)$ is the number of zeroes in the critical strip where the same condition holds).

This week, a new revision to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07741) was currently released, and I stumbled upon it. It claims that

$$\liminf_{t\to\infty} \frac{N_0(t)}{N(t)} = 1.$$

Given that versions of it have been up for the past almost 8 months, I'm imagining it's not correct (otherwise it would have been reviewed and accepted by now), but I don't know enough analytic number theory to refute it and I haven't been able to find any commentary on it. Furthermore, the paper passes many of the "crank tests" (well-formatted, well-written and structured, etc.), so it is unlikely to be complete garbage.

Can anyone with more knowledge of analytic number theory confirm or refute (or find a reference confirming or refuting) this paper's validity?

Comment: The paper is in the GM section, not the NT section of the Arxiv.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Forgive my ignorance, but what exactly does that mean? Does it mean since it's misclassified it's less likely to be correct? Also, can the downvoter please explain what I can do to improve the question or make it more suitable for math.stackexchange?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yeah, I know. Some follow-up questions (if this result is accurate) would be: 1) Does this give any sort of constructive progress towards the RH? 2) Does a result like this on natural density allow us to prove any results about the distribution of primes, etc. (weaker than those the full RH would imply but stronger than are known now)?

Comment: The GM section is where crank papers submitted to Arxiv are dumped. Certainly then, the Arxiv administrators are sceptical about the paper.

Comment: eight month does not sound like a red flag to me, not all correct papers are accepted and published within 8 months. Didn't know about the GM section though.

Comment: At least the paper is using the functional equation and that $\mu(n) \in \{-1,0,1\}$ so it may be at least partially valid. If you want to find the main ideas and if they are different from the traditional approach you should ask people like Lucia and GH on mathoverflow.

Comment: The traditional approach for the density of zeros on the critical line is very well explained and discussed in Bombieri http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1974-1975__17__176_0.pdf